# Multithreading with shared_ptr

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I gos tuck in my simple multithreading application which I am using as a simple test bench. What I want to achieve is to modify value of one variable passed to multiple threads and after all are done read the result.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

void updateValue(const std::shared_ptr<int>& value);

int main()
{
    auto sp = std::make_shared<int>(0);
    std::thread incrementThread_1(updateValue,sp);
    std::thread incrementThread_2(updateValue,sp);
    incrementThread_1.join();
    incrementThread_2.join();
    std::cout << *sp << std::endl;
}

void updateValue(const std::shared_ptr<int>& value)
{
    std::mutex g_i_mutex;
    for(int i = 0; i<100;i++)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(g_i_mutex);
        (*value)++;
        lk.unlock();
    }
}
```

Currently it just crashes. I don't have any meaningful info in debug window, so it's also not helping. Can someone please tell me what I might did wrong?

One thing to point out - **I don't want to use global variables**, because the functions originally are in different files.

Comment: What's the point of each thread having its own mutex? And why are you unlocking the `unique_lock` manually?

Comment: One thing you're doing wrong is that the `g_i_mutex` is a local variable so each thread will get its own copy, so you're never going to fail to take the mutex.

Comment: @Praetorian Those are great questions. `unique_lock` I am unlocking manually, because I understood that in such case it should be this way. As for mutex, I might make mistake indeed there.

Comment: In other words: if your intent is that each thread gets exclusive access to the shared `int`, this is not going to work. For that to work each thread has to lock the same mutex. The shown code uses a separate mutex for each thread. This accomplishes absolutely nothing useful, whatsoever.

Comment: Each thread has it's own `std::mutex` which is not doing what you expect. You need to pass a single instance around, like you are passing around a single `int`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik so, I should so something like `auto shared_mutex = std::make_shared<std::mutex>()`?

Comment: @sebap123 You don't need a `shared_mutex`.  What you need to do though is *share* a single mutex with both threads.  You can do that by passing it by reference to each thread or making it global.

Comment: @NathanOliver to avoid confusion @sebap123 was naming his `shared_ptr<std::mutex>` shared_mutex rather than refering to the type [std::shared_mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Oops.  Thanks for that.

Comment: No, there's no need to `unlock`, it'll be done automatically when the `unique_lock` object is destroyed in each iteration of the `for`. You don't even need a `unique_lock`, `lock_guard` is sufficient for your use case. And why bother with `std::make_shared<std::mutex>()`? Just have a global `mutex` and an `extern` declaration to allow it to be used in multiple files.

Comment: Neither of the comments above address app crashing.

Comment: There seems to be no need for a shared pointer in this code.

Comment: @KerrekSB - this is SAMPLE code. I know that here it isn't But I don't want to put the whole code.

Comment: @sebap123: What do you mean -- shared_ptr is *in your question title*!

Comment: @KerrekSB I am talking about `int` shared_ptr. I am going to use other data type. This is what I mean.

Comment: OK, but what I meant is that you don't need the `shared_ptr`. You could just pass the int by reference directly. The shared pointer buys you nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data that is shared between threads needs to ship its own mutex (which is shared with the exact same set of threads) and require all accessors to agree to use that mutex to serialize access.

A typical solution is to provide a custom type to encapsulate this responsibility. With this approach, your code would look roughly as follows:

```
struct SyncInt
{
    int n = 0;
    std::mutex mx;
};

void updateValue(SyncInt & value)
{
    for (int i = 0; i != 100; ++i)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(value.mx);
        ++value.n;
    }
}

int main()
{
    SyncInt v;
    std::thread t1(updateValue, std::ref(v)), t2(updateValue, std::ref(v));
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    std::cout << v.n << "\n";
}
```

(Note that the shared pointer in your example was not material to the question regarding concurrency, since all your code only ever used the pointee, never the pointer itself.)

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I never thought about using structure as a container.

Answer (score 1):

> Currently it just crashes. Can someone please tell me what I might did
>   wrong?

You are updating shared variable `value` from 2 different thread actually without any synchronization. This is data race condition which is Undefined Behavior. The simplest way to fix it is to make `g_i_mutex` global:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

std::mutex g_i_mutex;

void updateValue(const std::shared_ptr<int>& value);

int main()
{
    auto sp = std::make_shared<int>(0);
    std::thread incrementThread_1(updateValue,sp);
    std::thread incrementThread_2(updateValue,sp);
    incrementThread_1.join();
    incrementThread_2.join();
    std::cout << *sp << std::endl;
}

void updateValue(const std::shared_ptr<int>& value)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<100;i++)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(g_i_mutex);
        (*value)++;
        lk.unlock();
    }
}
```

Another solution without global variable:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

void updateValue(const std::shared_ptr<int>& value, std::mutex& g_i_mutex)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<100;i++)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(g_i_mutex);
        (*value)++;
        lk.unlock();
    }
}

int main()
{
    auto sp = std::make_shared<int>(0);
    std::mutex g_i_mutex;
    std::thread incrementThread_1(updateValue, sp, std::ref(g_i_mutex));
    std::thread incrementThread_2(updateValue, sp, std::ref(g_i_mutex));
    incrementThread_1.join();
    incrementThread_2.join();
    std::cout << *sp << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Well, that would work, if only I'd have global mutex. I knew that this is solution, but I cannot have it like that (I even highlighted it in the question).

Answer (score 0):

On the merits of the question, there is no need to use `shared_ptr` in this scenario at all. All you need is an `atomic<int>`.

Answer (score -3):

You want to use a data structure something like this, which strongly ties your mutex to the piece of data it's protecting access to:

```
class somethingShared
{
    int        m_value;
    std::mutex m_mtx;

    public:
    somethingShared( int initialVal ) : m_value( initialVal ) { }

    void increment()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m_mtx);
        ++m_value;
    }

    int value() const { return m_value; }

};

void updateValue( somethingShared & value)
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < 100; ++i )
    {
        value.increment();
    }
}
```

N.B. I haven't compiled or run this, it's just to show the general idea.

Comment: Try it any online compiler, and you will see.

Comment: Not at all is not very helpful. I think should be also a lock in the `value()` accessor, although in this example it might work without it (due to the thread.join synchronization).

Comment: Replace the thread creation with `std::thread incrementThread_1([&sp](){ updateValue(sp); });`, since otherwise it will try to copy somethingShared, which is not possible.